# Decoding SNMP OIDs using tshark (wireshark)

Tags: linux, snmp, wireshark, tshark

I am debugging an SNMP trap problem using tshark (TShark 1.6.6) on a Linux platform.  (The target platform does not support the wireshark GUI.)  OIDs in PDUs are shown in numerical format even though I have MIBs installed in `/usr/share/snmp/mibs` with a link to that in `/usr/local/share/mibs`.  I tried `-V`.  There doesn't appear to be a tshark verbose or debugging option except for some memory debugging options.  I have checked the man page and find nothing on SNMP or MIBs.  I tried `strace` and I found a file `/usr/share/wireshark/oid` file but when I put the MIB directory there, I get a `flex` error, and a google search for what this mysterious file means turns up nothing.  I can copy and paste the OIDs into an `snmptranslate` command and it correctly translates them. I tried creating a `~/.wireshark` directory with `smi_modules` and `smi_paths` (`"/usr/share/snmp/mibs"`).  I did a `tshark -G currentprefs` to see if there was a relevant preference but there isn't.  I have googled this issue but I get way too much chaff to make any progress.  I checked unix.stackexchange.com, superuser.com, and this site.  I verified that people ask wireshark questions on this site (10,000 of them) to make sure it was on topic.

Example invocation:

```
tshark -R "snmp && ip.dst==<nms_ip>" -i eth0
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on eth0
  4.675952  <agent_ip> -> <nms_ip>  SNMP 115 sNMPv2-Trap 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0
```

Contents of `~/.wireshark/preferences`:

```
name_resolve: mtC
name_resolve_load_smi_modules: TRUE
snmp.display_oid: TRUE
snmp.desegment: TRUE
snmp.var_in_tree: TRUE
```

How do I get the OIDs to be displayed in symbolic format, e.g. `sysUpTimeInstance` and `snmpTrapOID.0`?

Comment: The "snmptranslate" command is a net-snmp tool. It has no relation to how well tshark does on doing the same thing. Just thought you could use that information. I've never gotten along with Wireshark's MIB loading functionality, myself, so I can't really offer anything more useful than that.

Comment: @Jolta: Well, I do realize that they don't in theory map one to the other, but that's to prove I at least have the right mibs installed.  One site told me that Wireshark looked for mibs in /usr/local/share/mibs so I made the link to /usr/share/snmp/mibs, so I was just demonstrating as a sanity check that snmptranslate can parse them.

Comment: Yes, it tells us that the mibs are installed correctly for snmptranslate to find them.

Comment: @Jolta:  I had hoped that setting `~/.wireshark/smi_paths` to the `net-snmp` mib directory would be sufficient to direct `tshark` to the mibs, but it doesn't seem so.  Thanks for your input, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the information [Resolving SNMP OID in snmpbulkwalk and tshark](http://blog.ip.fi/2010/07/snmp-oid-resolving-in-snmpbulkwalk-and.html)  useful.

Adding my MIBs to ~/.wireshark/smi_modules (via wireshark name resolution preferences), and ensuring the MIBs were located in the correct location

(on a mac I used dtrace to trace which files 'tshark' was accessing and located the path as /usr/share/snmp/mibs)